# Why isn't strlen working for me?

Tags: c++, string

```
char p[4]={'h','g','y'};
cout<<strlen(p);
```

This code prints 3.

```
char p[3]={'h','g','y'};
cout<<strlen(p);
```

This prints 8.

```
char p[]={'h','g','y'};
cout<<strlen(p);
```

This again prints 8.

Please help me as I can't figure out why three different values are printed by changing the size of the array.

Comment: Also, use `char p[] = "hgy";`

Comment: @Paul: Because about 17 people formatted it simultaneously. The simultaneous-edit warning only works if the edits take more than a minute or so.

Comment: This has a `C++` tag, Why are you working with C strings in C++ anyway? As you just found out, they are somewhat hard to use for beginners. Use `std::string`. It won't hide the madness completely, but it gets it down to a level where a novice can handle it.

Comment: @Johannes, Do you mean not enough initializers for the space?  Because in all cases I see there is sufficient space for the supplied initializers.

Comment: @Omnifarious, never mind me... I read it as a string literal instead of a braced list.

Comment: Congratulations on writing a buffer overflow with C strings! You have joined an elite group of coders who are beloved by hackers the world over.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) starts at the given pointer and advances until it reaches the character `'\0'`.  If you don't have a `'\0'` in your array, it could be *any* number until a `'\0'` is reached.

Another way to reach the number you're looking for (in the case you've shown) is by using: `int length = sizeof(p)/sizeof(*p);`, which will give you the length of the array.  However, that is not strictly the string length as defined by `strlen`.

As @John Dibling mentions, the reason that `strlen` gives the correct result on your first example is that you've allocated space for 4 characters, but only used 3; the remaining 1 character is automatically initialized to 0, which is exactly the `'\0'` character that `strlen` looks for.

Comment: +1 this is a good response.  Only thing I would add is an explanation why the first code snippet works. In `char p[4]={'h','g','y'};` p is 4 chars, but only 3 were initialized explicitly, so the compiler initializes all remaining (unspecified) elements to `0`.

Comment: I totally agree with the comment above.

Answer (score 4):

Only your first example has a null terminated array of characters - the other two examples have no null termination, so you can't use `strlen()` on them in a well-defined manner.

```
char p[4]={'h','g','y'}; // p[3] is implicitly initialized to '\0'

char p[3]={'h','g','y'}; // no room in p[] for a '\0' terminator

char p[]={'h','g','y'};  // p[] implicitly sized to 3 - also no room for '\0'
```

Note that in the last case, if you used a string literal to initialize the array, you would get a null terminator:

```
char p[]= "hgy";  // p[] has 4 elements, last one is '\0'
```

Answer (score 1):

That will get you a random number.  `strlen` requires that strings be terminated with a `'\0`' to work.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the number will be undefined, not random.  (i.e. don't use strlen() as the basis for your lottery results ;^))

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
char p[4]={'h','g','y', '\0'};
```

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` is a standard library function that works with *strings* (in C sense of the term). *String* is defined as an array of `char` values that ends with a `\0` value. If you supply something that is not a *string* to `strlen`, the behavior is undefined: the code might crash, the code might produce meaningless results etc.

In your examples only the first one supplies `strlen` with a *string*, which is why it works as expected. In the second and the third case, what you supply is not a string (not terminated with `\0`), which is why the results expectedly make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

`'\0'` terminate your char buffer.

```
char p[4]={'h','g','y', '\0'};
```

Comment: In this specific example the final `\0` is unnecessary.  All unspecified elements will be initialized to zero.

Answer (score -1):

This is because strlen() expects to find a null-terminator for the string. In this case, you don't have it, so strlen() keeps counting until it finds a \0 or gives a memory access violation and your program dies. RIP!