# char array not returning correct size

Tags: c++, arduino

```
  Serial.begin(57600);
  char testArray6[6] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'};
  Serial.println(testArray6);
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray6));
  char testArray5[5] = {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray5));
  char testArray4[4] = {'0', '0', '0', '0'};
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray4));
  char testArray3[3] = {'0', '0', '0'};
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray3));
  char testArray2[2] = {'0', '0'};
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray2));
}
```

```
12345600000000000000
20
14
9
5
2
```

Im not sure if something is wrong with how I am initializing the char array or if I am using the strlen function incorrectly.

Comment: Note that you're programming in ***C++*** not C.

Comment: C++ duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2609104/995714

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in C are *null-terminated* sequences of characters, so what are passed to `strlen()` must be pointers to *null-terminated* sequence of characters.

Add terminating null-characters to the array to fix:

```
  Serial.begin(57600);
  char testArray6[7] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '\0'};
  Serial.println(testArray6);
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray6));
  char testArray5[6] = {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\0'};
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray5));
  char testArray4[5] = {'0', '0', '0', '0', '\0'};
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray4));
  char testArray3[4] = {'0', '0', '0', '\0'};
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray3));
  char testArray2[3] = {'0', '0', '\0'};
  Serial.println(strlen(testArray2));
}
```

Comment: I would rather recommend not using an explicit size at all, and use a "normal" string as initializer. E.g. `char testArray2[] = "00";`

Answer (score 0):

In `C` a string must end with `\0`.

```
a[5] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'};
```